# 404 error from external web browser

Tags: tomcat

I have a web service deployed to a Tomcat server which is running in Windows Server 2008. When I invoke the web service from an internal browser on the web server, it works perfectly.

However, when I attempt to use the same URL to access the web service from another computer, I get a "404 - File or directory not found" error.

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: not enough information.  what do the logs say?  is the same webapp bound to all IPS? is the context done by host name? (virtual hosting)

Comment: If you can tell me where to find this information I will try to provide it.

Comment: should be in %CATALINA_HOME%/logs (in the logs directory of your tomcat install, normally)

Comment: It doesn't appear that any logging takes place when this happens. At least nothing in the default log files.

Comment: To clarify, in the localhost access log, I can see the successful, internal calls, but nothing about the failed, external attempts.

Comment: are you sure that the external calls are actually making it to tomcat?

Comment: doesn't the 404 error suggest that they are, and that tomcat just can't find the requested resource?

Comment: What's the URL format in both cases?

Comment: i'm using the same url in both cases: servername.acpl.lib.in.us/APNS_WebService/rest/operations/operationName?parame=paramvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with the firewall. I don't really understand why it gave me the 404 error.